# imges on gitub pages not appear

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, htmlelements

I am trying for two days to resolve the images not appearing issue on Github pages. I searched and applied all the ways.
Please guide me step by step and if possible with a screenshot. the answer with ../ is not working. I am confused about where to put it. should I edit the indes.html file inside the repository file or just edit in the local file on the desktop and then upload it. my spelling and case are also correct.

here is the link to the repository
https://github.com/biqrar/Responsive-QR-Code-card.git

Comment: Use a CDN or base64.

Comment: Please read the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552) where the answer is No.

Comment: image path for github is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Perhaps I misunderstand your question, but is it as simple as the path to your image is wrong? Within your repository the qr png image and your webpage reside in the same folder. So changing **line 32** of *index.html* to  `src="image-qr-code.png"` makes it display.

Comment: huge thanks, the problem was that I first used [" /images/image-qr-code.png"] for VS Code live server extension. in this case, the image was in the images folder. when I uploaded to GitHub pages I didn't change /images/image-qr-code.png to "images-qr-code.png", hence It was denying from display.

Answer (score 3):

What I see is that the image file is in the same path of index.
so the path for source of image should be only file name

```
<img src="image-qr-code.png"
      class="card-img-top mt-2 px-2 py-2 mb-2"
      alt="QR-code"
/>
```

Comment: Huge thanks. for newbies, it is impossible to thrive without the help of this empathetic community.